# Battery API is not working on chrome pop up window

Tags: api, google-chrome, battery

is there a way to get the Battery object in chrome pop up windows

I am using this code to create pop up

```
chrome.windows.create({'url': 'mypop.html', 'type': 'popup'}, function(window) {
  });
```

but having problem to return the battery object using this code

```
var battery = navigator.webkitBattery;
```

when I am calling the javascript file on the mypop.html page.

Is it the chrome security issue that disallow battery object on pop up page?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its been removed from Chrome as `navigator.webkitBattery` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Chrome developer advocate has replied over here on SO.
Checkout this thread.

[navigator.webkitBattery not working in Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522527/navigator-webkitbattery-not-working-in-google-chrome)