# navigator.webkitBattery not working in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, battery

Im trying to get the battery level through battery api. It works fine in firefox.  But in chrome (navigator.webkitBattery) is not working. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery || navigator.webkitBattery;

alert(battery.level)
```

Answer (score 8):

well, on chrome ver 39.0+, there is navigator.getBattery method, which return a promise object when call. so the code could be like below:

```
var battery = navigator.battery || navigator.mozBattery;
if (battery) {
    // battery status for firefox 
    alert(battery.level * 100 + '%');
} else if (navigator.getBattery) {
    //battery status for chrome
    navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
        alert(battery.level * 100 + '%');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The shortest answer is that it is not implemented, and is not going to be implemented for a little while.

Update: Jan 2015.  This is now available in Chrome (see answer below)