# Getting battery status in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, battery

I am trying to get battery status in chrome browser using the following code

```
var battery=navigator.battery||navigator.webkitBattery||navigator.mozBattery;
document.writeln(Math.round(battery.level*100)+"%");
```

Its working in mozilla but not in chrome.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446407/battery-api-is-not-working-on-chrome-pop-up-window) question on SO stated that its removed from chrome,but it was asked a year before.
Is there any  way to get battery status in chrome?

Note: By battery status ,I mean the battery status of the desktop computer.Its for a computer and not for mobile device.

Comment: By battery status ,I mean the battery status of the desktop computer.Its for a computer and not for mobile device.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-the-battery-status-api/

Written late last year but same issue. Perhaps Chrome doesn't have it implemented.

Comment: It's not yet available in ChromeOS (http://crbug.com/122593), so it will probably not exist in desktop Chrome either.

Comment: Well, as far as I know most desktops don't _have_ a battery. Are you sure you don't mean laptops?

Comment: @11684:Ya I mean laptops too.

Answer (score 3):

#### navigator.getBattery()

While its use is discouraged, as it is considered to be obsolete, you can technically use [`navigator.getBattery()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery) to access the [`BatteryManager.level`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BatteryManager/level) because it is [currently supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=battery-status) in Chrome:

```
(async () => {
  const battery = await navigator.getBattery();
  const battery_level = `${battery.level * 100}%`;

  console.log(battery_level); // 100%
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this Chrome extension but they require you to download an Intel plugin for your computer. (there's a link in the extension)

Chrome extension: http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/battery-status/bpbkgeonjocononjcojndjbfpcodainm